# Correctly type return value of fromJS function with flow

Tags: flowtype, immutable.js

Giving the following code:

```
const copy = fromJS([
  {
    points: 1000,
  },
  {
    points: 1001,
  },
  {
    points: 200,
  },
]);

copy.map(() => {});
```

After migrating from immutable.js `3.8` to `4.0.0-rc.12` I get the following error:

> Cannot call `copy.map` because property `map` is missing in `mixed`.

`fromJS`'s return value is typed as `mixed` now and I can't set it to `List`.

```
const copy: List<Map<*, *>> = fromJS([
  {
    points: 1000,
  },
  {
    points: 1001,
  },
  {
    points: 200,
  },
]);

copy.map(() => {});
```

gives me:

> Cannot assign `fromJS(...)` to `copy` because `mixed` is incompatible with `List`